# vb net 2008 setup project, msaccess db points to different folder

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2003

I have this problem after installing my project. The ms access database I included in the "application files" in setup project is not being used by the project itself. The program works fine until ANY query is executed.

The connectionstring I used points to the included ms access db file which is "DataSource=|DataDirectory|\MyDB.mdb"

After any query executes, this MyDB is ignored, instead it CREATES a new database file with same name in this location

C:\Users\myPC\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files\myproject\

My installation path is

C:\Program Files\myproject

I tried installing in 3 different machines:
Win7 (this one used for development, VS2008 installed) - problem occured

Win 8.1(VS2008 installed) - problem occured

WinXp (VS2008 NOT installed) - works fine

Does vs 2008 being installed have anything to do with my problem?

Comment: are you saying that you had `DataDirectory` set to `C:\Program Files\myproject`?

Comment: I dont recall setting DataDirectory to any path. I thought it automatically points to where the .exe belongs?

Comment: Your app is not supposed to store data in `C:\Program Files...` and it likely does have permission to do so.  When they try, the OS redirects to `VirtualStore`.  A better way is to store the data in `AppData` and access it there (use `Environment.GetFolder` to get the name to use).

Comment: Much appreciated plutonix! Worked for me

Comment: Generally `C:\Program Files...` doesn't allow to make any changes without administrator privileges. Run your .exe with admin privileges and you should be able to use `C:\Program Files...`.

The reason you couldn't run it on Win8.1 or Win7 isn't the VS 2008 but UAC. XP doesn't have a UAC.

Comment: after reading some stuff around, Windows vista and higher does not allow writing to c:\program files without raised user privileges. It would require manifest for UAC virtualisation which I would not use at the moment. Seems like I have a lot to consider before try to distribute my project. Thanks for guiding me to the correct path @Mahadev